# Kinect with zoom lens calibration: Bad link on ros wiki

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to view documentation about calibrating the Kinect using a Zoom lens.  The link suggested by
[www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_calibration/technical](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect_calibration/technical))

leads to this dead link:
[www.ros.org/doc/api/kinect_near_mode_calibration/html](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/kinect_near_mode_calibration/html))

Why is this documentation no longer on the server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54068/kinect-with-zoom-lens-calibration:-bad-link-on-ros-wiki/) by [ee.cornwell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4115/ee.cornwell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out docs embedded in https://svn.code.sf.net/p/jsk-ros-pkg/code/trunk/jsk_common/jsk_openni_kinect/kinect_near_mode_calibration/launch/kinect_near_mode_calibration.launch

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2014-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0